# 'TypeError: Scalar value for argument 'color' is not numeric' when using opencv-python drawing a circle

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I'm new to opencv.Some weird things happened when I drew a circle.It didn't work when I tried to pass c2 to the circle function,but it worked well when I pass c1 to the color argument. But **c1 == c2**.

Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 

canvas = np.zeros((300, 300, 3), dtype='uint8')
for _ in range(1):
    r = np.random.randint(0, 200)
    center = np.random.randint(0, 300, size=(2, )) 
    color = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(3, ))
    c1 = tuple(color.tolist())
    c2 = tuple(color)
    print('c1 == c2 : {} '.format(c1 == c2))
    cv2.circle(canvas, tuple(center), r, c2, thickness=-1)

cv2.imshow('Canvas', canvas)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

when I use c2,the console printed:'TypeError: Scalar value for argument 'color' is not numeric',but why it happened when **c1 == c2**?Thanks.

Comment: You could print c1 or c2 (not the equality) and see what they are

Answer (score 20, accepted):

- Convert data type int64 to int.
- [`ndarray.tolist()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) : data items are converted to the nearest compatible builtin Python type, via the [`item`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.item.html#numpy.ndarray.item) function.

**Ex.**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 

canvas = np.zeros((300, 300, 3), dtype='uint8')
for _ in range(1):
    r = np.random.randint(0, 200)
    center = np.random.randint(0, 300, size=(2, )) 
    color = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(3, ))

    #convert data types int64 to int
    color = ( int (color [ 0 ]), int (color [ 1 ]), int (color [ 2 ])) 
    cv2.circle(canvas, tuple(center), r, tuple (color), thickness=-1)


cv2.imshow('Canvas', canvas)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.It works well in your way.But why does tuple(center) work without any additional processing when they all receive the same tuple type.

Comment: @Qiuhong Luo Color is a combination of the three primary BGR colors and values are used ranging from 0 to 255 (int type) for each of the components. And the center, It is coordinates of circle. The coordinates are represented as tuples of two values i.e. (X coordinate value, Y coordinate value).

Comment: @bharatk Sorry I dont understand. Why color needs the additional int processing?

Comment: Probably because opencv is picky and was designed for c++ ._.

Comment: "Convert data type int64 to int." - May I ask, to which int datatype? uint8? int32?...

Comment: - Answer: None of those, we need ndarray.tolist(). Other options (tuple(my_array), [int(elem) for elem in my_array], ...) keep the dtype of the values as numpy dtypes, making the function fail.